# Wrap panel in windows-phone 7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, wrappanel

I want to use wrap panel in my silverlight phone application.
I downloaded and installed the Silverlight for Windows Phone Toolkit - Aug 2011.msi, but I can't still use wrap panel.
Is there any other task that I have to do to use wrap panel?
And I want to use it in Blend 4. What should I do?

Answer (score 3):

Remember that just because you install the .msi file doesn't mean its in your application. You have to add a reference to the Windows Phone toolkit. The best way to do that is to use [Nuget](http://nuget.org/) and it will add the necessary .dll's to your application.

**UPDATE:**
Once you install Nuget, just search for the [Silverlight for Windows Phone Toolkit](http://nuget.org/packages/SilverlightToolkitWP). After that check out this [article](http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/WP7-WrapPanel-in-depth).

Comment: @aakpro No problem. Just make sure you mark this as answered by clicking the arrow next to my answer. Thanks.